# Including extra data into Passport middleware with Express

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

A user is coming to my web route from another application with a link that was generated in this form: `/auth/steam/:id/:token`, where `:id` and `:token` are not required for this Passport middleware. They are just parameters I want to keep track of.

When the user successfully authenticates, I want to have access to these values from the initial web request to `/auth/steam/`. My routes currently look like this:

```
this.app.get('/auth/steam/:id/:token', passport.authenticate('steam'), () => {

});

this.app.get('/auth/steam/return', passport.authenticate('steam', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), (req, res) => {
  // Would like access to id and token here

  res.render('index');
});
```

Is it possible to keep data along with the request into the return route, etc. where I noted I want to use the values? I was thinking of using a session but was hoping to avoid that.

Thanks!

Update: I've tried using `express-session` to add data to the session like so:

```
this.app.get('/auth/steam/:id/:token', passport.authenticate('steam'), (res, req) => {
  req.session.discord_id = req.params.id;
  req.session.token = req.params.token;
  this.logger.info('Redirecting to Steam');
});

this.app.get('/auth/steam/return', passport.authenticate('steam', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), (req, res) => {
  console.log('session', req.session.token);
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

The problem is when arriving back at `/auth/steam/return`, the session has been updated with the new session from the OpenID request. My data no longer is there.

Comment: I mean... if you're redirecting, can't you just pass said params along with the redirect if they exist?

Comment: (1) Shouldn't your params in the lambda function in your session update be (req, res) => ... with request being the first parameter, not response?
(2) Regarding the passing of the parameters. OpenID (as specified) must pass and additional/unknown query parameters sent to the auth endpoint through to the return callback. If steam implemented their backend compliant, you just should add the params to the auth req and they should come in back at the return route

Comment: If you want to try cookie base authentication
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158386/implement-cookie-based-authentication-in-node-js-with-passport

Hopefully it will work !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You obviously don't want a custom login strategy since Steam has it's own OpenID strategy (https://github.com/liamcurry/passport-steam).

Using sessions is probably the way to go as you've tried, and I believe you can make a couple tweaks to your `'/auth/steam/:id/:token'` route to make it work. I provided an example that switches the order of your `passport.authenticate('steam')` call with your other callback (which would never get to since the passport.authenticate() would redirect you), uses express's middleware `next()` function, and includes a `req.session.save()`, which actually saves the session back to the store you're using (documentation in https://github.com/expressjs/session). Let me know if using the following as your new route doesn't save the session's discord_id and token properties when you get back to `'/auth/steam/return'`

```
this.app.get('/auth/steam/:id/:token', (req, res, next) => {
  req.session.discord_id = req.params.id;
  req.session.token = req.params.token;
  this.logger.info('Redirecting to Steam');
  req.session.save(next);
}, passport.authenticate('steam'));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! Works great. Could you explain why you pass the callback to `req.session.save()`?

Comment: That simply allows you to support handling an error if saving your session fails for whatever reason. you technically don't need to pass 'next' as the callback and can just call it after req.session.save() without passing a callback to save(), but technically your session could fail to save and you wouldn't know about it until you got back to your return route. More on express error handling here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: I've tired your solution but the session is still `undefined` in the callback route. Could you provide a full example and the `express-session` configuration you are using, please?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to implement a custom login strategy. This can be done by changing your strategy to get the req parameters inside the strategy callback:

```
passport.use('steam',
            new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField: 'email',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback: true 
        },
        function(req, email, password, done) {
            //Do your authentication here
            /**Some Authentication Logic **/
              //Get Parameters from the request object...
                 var id = req.params.id;
                 var token = req.params.token
                 var info = {id:id,token:token};
                 return done(error,user,info);
            });

        }));
```

And then you can access the info object in the request. Here is an example of the sort of function you would use:

```
function loginUser(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('steam', function(err, user, info) { 
        //custom callback requires you to login
        // your custom variables are in the info object       
        req.login(user, loginErr => {
            if (!loginErr) {
                return res.status(200).json({
                    success: true,
                    err: null,
                    message: 'Logged in correctly!',
                    id: info.id,
                    token: info.token
                });
            } else
                return res.status(401).json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Unable to login!'
                });
        });
    })(req, res, next);
}
```

Once again, this can be customized to the sort of functionality you are looking to implement. If you use a custom callback, you need to call the req.login function manually, but this gives you a lot more control on the sort of function you are trying to implement.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works for me, as I can add anything to the info field and use it in passport authenticate custom middleware

Answer (score -1):

Many people use express's [session module](https://github.com/expressjs/session) for this task.

Once session is installed you can simply do
`req.session.token = req.params.token;`
and then in your other handler retrieve it with `req.session.token`

You can also assign properties to the passport instance, but this is a bad idea.

Comment: I placed what you recommended inside my first route (after adding req and res args to the callback), and then tried logging in the response handler. The values were undefined and it looks like the whole session is getting overwritten by the time it gets to the return handler.